# Java Library for World / US Map

Tags: java

### Context

I'm developing an application in Java. I want a fairly high resolution map/globe of the World/US. This is for an application involving:

```
* plotting where certain landmarks are
* plotting where certain earth quakes happened
* plotting where certain companies are headquartered
* overlaying a weather map
```

### Question

Is there an open source library for this? [Likely not given that map data is expensive.]

Comment: You could consider the NASA WorldWind project http://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenStreetMap may be able to help. I don't know if they provide for exactly what you need, and  their maps come in XML or JSON so you have to parse them - but there are libraries for that bit. Might be worth a look though...